# Flutter setState not updating RichText widget

Tags: flutter, setstate, richtext

I am trying to populate a RichText widget with asynchronously received messages.  The messages are stored in a list of TextSpan objects.  In the attached example I am adding objects to the list from a timer but the RichText widget is not showing the new messages.  Is anyone able to see what I'm doing incorrectly?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: TstWidget(name: 'tst'),
    );
  }
}

class TstWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String name;
  TstWidget({this.name});

  @override
  _TstWidgetState createState() => _TstWidgetState();
}

class _TstWidgetState extends State<TstWidget> {
  Timer _timer;
  int _idx = 10;
  List<TextSpan> _messages = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Create a couple of initial messages just so see something in the RichText widget.
    _messages.add(TextSpan(text: 'pre set message 1\n'));
    _messages.add(TextSpan(text: 'pre set message 2\n'));

    _timer = new Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 1), (time) {
      print('adding message $_idx');
      setState(() {
        _messages.add(TextSpan(text: 'this is message $_idx\n'));
      });

      if (--_idx == 0) {
        print('timer complete');
        _timer.cancel();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.name),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(width: 1)),
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                child: RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(
                    children: _messages,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This case is not supported by Flutter. The docs for `children` property of TextSpan:

> Modifying the list after the TextSpan has been created is not supported and may have unexpected results.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextSpan/children.html

Simple solution is to copy the list on each render:

```
child: RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    children: List.from(_messages),
  ),
),
```

Different, probably better solution would be to have seperate TextSpans (map messages to TextSpan) for each message like in the example:

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    text: 'Hello ',
    style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
    children: <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(text: 'bold', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      TextSpan(text: ' world!'),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The widget is not updating because you're not changing the actual `List` object but just adding more items to the existing `List` object.

And [setState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html)

> Notif[ies] the framework that the internal state of this object has changed.

And so for you to actually change the state of your `_messages` object, you need to create a new `List` with the updated items and assign it to your `_messages` variable so the framework can detect that the state has changed.

So to do that, you should update:

```
setState(() {
        _messages.add(TextSpan(text: 'this is message $_idx\n'));
      });
```

to:

```
setState(() {
        _messages  = [..._messages, TextSpan(text: 'this is message $_idx\n'))];
      });
```